# How do I insert the first line of one file into the first line of another?

Tags: text-processing, sed, head

I've got a `head` command to get the first line of a file and a `sed` command to insert before the first line of a file. How do I combine these so I can insert the extracted first line of one file before the first line of another file.

**Get first line of a file**

```
head -n 1 file_to_get_first_line_from
```

**Insert before first line**

```
sed -i '1 i\insert_this_in_the_first_line' file_to_intert_into
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `file_to_insert_into` does not end with trailing newline:

```
$ cat <<IN > file_to_insert_into
$(head -n1 file_to_get_first_line_from; cat file_to_insert_into)
IN
```

Comment: Prolly the best/fastest in this particular case so +. Can't be reused though if requirements change (e.g. insert before 21st line).

Answer (score 1):

The most portable way to do this is by using [POSIX specified features of `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

```
$ cat file1
Jack and Jill
Went up the hill
To fetch a pail of water.

$ cat file2
Nursery Rhymes:
Epic Poems:
Classic Literature:

$ printf '%s\n' '0r !head -n 1 file2' x | ex file1

$ cat file1
Nursery Rhymes:
Jack and Jill
Went up the hill
To fetch a pail of water.
```

- `printf` is used to send commands to `ex`.
- `0` is the address given to the `r`ead command; it tells `ex` to read in the specified text "after line 0" (i.e. before line 1).
- `!head -n 1 file2` means that instead of `r`eading text directly from a file (a *whole* file), the `head` command is executed first and its output is read in (at the specified position, line 0).
- `x` means save and exit.

This is fully POSIX compliant and portable.

---

If you were scripting this it would be good practice to check your assumptions: That `file2` exists and is readable, and that `file1` is readable and writable if it exists.

```
if [ -r file2 ] && [ -f file2 ] && { ! [ -e file1 ] || { [ -r file1 ] && [ -w file1 ];};}; then
  printf '%s\n' '0r !head -n 1 file2' x | ex file1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: Thanks to @Wildcard for pointing out GNU Sed difference

### BSD `sed`

Try on your terminal:

```bash
sed -i '' "1i\
$(head -n 1 file_to_get_first_line_from)" file_to_insert_into
```

- This means start typing `sed -i '' "1i\`, then hit enter to continue the rest of the command

#### Explanation

- Helps combine your two original commands via Bash command substitution `$(` `)`. Replaces whatever bash commands are inside `$(` `)`, with its output
- We change `'` literal quotes to `"` quotes in order to allow Bash to act while still using quotes for `sed` to properly see one sed command

### GNU `sed`

Or if you have GNU sed:

```bash
sed -i "1i $(head -n 1 file_to_get_first_line_from)" file_to_insert_into
```

- Tested with `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. To see your sed version: `sed --version`
- GNU sed can omit the `\` and newline. `info sed`, under `sed Programs`, `Common Commands`:

> As a GNU extension, if between the 'a' and the newline there is other than a whitespace-'\' sequence, then the text of this line, starting at the first non-whitespace character after the 'a', is taken as the first line of the TEXT block.  (This enables a simplification in scripting a one-line add.)  This extension also works with the 'i' and 'c' commands.

### Additional info

- Optionally, there is a shorter version of the head command: `head -1`. However `info head` claims this is a `obsolete option syntax -[NUM]...` that head supports, and recommends for "standard hosts" to use the `-n NUM` syntax instead, so we can just continue to use your original `head -n 1` syntax here

Comment: This depends on GNU `sed`; POSIX compatibility requires a backslash and newline after `i` to delimit the text to be inserted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Wildcard. Answer updated about this difference.

Answer (score 0):

With Vim and `head`:

```
vim -Nesc '0r !head -n1 file_to_get_first_line_from' +wq file_to_insert_into
```

- `-Nes` starts no-compatible, silent, ex-mode, which is useful when you want to script tasks with Vim.
- [`-c '0r !<cmd>'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3Aread) inserts the output of the command `<cmd>` before the first line. The command here is, of course, the `head` command.
- `+wq` saves and closes the file.